# I have to extract all the rows in a .csv corresponding to the rows with 'watermelon' through pandas

Tags: python, csv

I am using this code. but instead of new with just the required rows, I'm getting an empty .csv with just the header.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("E:/Mac&cheese.csv")
newdf = df[df["fruit"]=="watermelon"+"*"]
newdf.to_csv("E:/Mac&cheese(2).csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in how you select the rows containing the word "watermelon". Instead of:

```
newdf = df[df["fruit"]=="watermelon"+"*"]
```

Try:

```
newdf = df[df["fruit"].str.contains("watermelon")]
```

In your example, pandas is literally looking for cells containing the word "watermelon*".

Answer (score 0):

missing the underscore in pd.read_csv on first call, also it looks like the actual location is incorrect. missing the // in the file location.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, it may have got edited in pasting. The code is working without error. But the file with required fields is not getting generated. the only header row is coming in the new .csv.